# How to properly refresh Context menu strip

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently stumped on trying to figure out how to properly refresh a context menu strip. I have tried a few different things and none of them have worked. The basic concept is very easy. The tray app displays a context menu strip that lets you start a service or stop it if it's already running. It should update or refresh every few seconds to check to see the status and then display items accordingly. Right now I just can't seem to get it to refresh properly and am in need of some guidance.

This is the `Main` method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    NotifyIcon trayicon = new NotifyIcon();
    trayicon.ContextMenuStrip = GetContext();
    trayicon.Icon = Properties.Resources.icon_error;
    trayicon.Visible = true;
    trayicon.Text = trayballoon;
    LoadSettings();
    Application.Run();
}
```

The Context menu is as follows

```
static ContextMenuStrip GetContext()
{
    ContextMenuStrip CMS = new ContextMenuStrip();
    if (getStatus() == "Running")
    {
        CMS.Items.Add("Pause", null, new EventHandler(Stop_Click));
        CMS.Items.Add("Stop", null, new EventHandler(Stop_Click));
    }
    else
    {
        CMS.Items.Add("Start", null, new EventHandler(Start_Click));
    }

    CMS.Items.Add("Set Automatic", null, new EventHandler(Auto_Click));
    CMS.Items.Add("Set Manual", null, new EventHandler(Manual_Click));

    CMS.Items.Add("Exit", null, new EventHandler(Exit_Click));
    return CMS;
    
}
```

I am unsure of where to place the refresh or how to access it, it would hypothetically be `CMS.Refresh()` but that wouldn't update unless it was called in the main method. Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't ASP.NET, is there a reason you tagged it?

Comment: Also, I don't know why you want to refresh the context strip, just update the existing one and it should redraw what it needs. My advice would be to add all 3 buttons and show/hide them as required.

Comment: @DavidG where would I show/hide? would that just go in the get context method? Showing/Hiding would work just fine in place of refreshing, I just used that to describe my goal as I want the menu to only display to valid options and later on have the icons change for the tray app. I tagged this ASP.NET as the application as a whole is both C# and ASP.NET so I just wanted to make sure I covered all my bases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest continually refreshing the context strip. Instead, it's much cleaner to just show and hide the items you need. The [`ToolStripItemCollection.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitemcollection.add?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_ToolStripItemCollection_Add_System_String_System_Drawing_Image_System_EventHandler_) method returns a reference to the newly added button, so you can just store those references for later use. Then use the [`ToolStripItem.Visible`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.visible?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_ToolStripItem_Visible) property to show/hide them as required.
For example:

```
// Somewhere to keep references to the buttons you need to modify
private static ToolStripItem _stopButton;
private static ToolStripItem _startButton;
private static ToolStripItem _pauseButton;

static ContextMenuStrip GetContext()
{
    ContextMenuStrip CMS = new ContextMenuStrip();

    // Store references to the buttons
    _pauseButton = CMS.Items.Add("Pause", null, new EventHandler(Stop_Click));
    _stopButton = CMS.Items.Add("Stop", null, new EventHandler(Stop_Click));
    _startButton = CMS.Items.Add("Start", null, new EventHandler(Start_Click));

    CMS.Items.Add("Set Automatic", null, new EventHandler(Auto_Click));
    CMS.Items.Add("Set Manual", null, new EventHandler(Manual_Click));

    CMS.Items.Add("Exit", null, new EventHandler(Exit_Click));
    return CMS;
}
```

Then in the method where you change the status of the app, for example:

```
public void SetButtonStatus(bool running)
{
    // Only show this when not running
    _startButton.Visible = !running; 

    _stopButton.Visible = running;
    _pauseButton .Visible = running;
}
```

Comment: at the moment the status changes in each of the Clicks, so Start_Click changes it and Stop_Click changes it. Would I run the SetRunning method in each click method? Or should I rework that and have it so the updates are all encased in one method?

Comment: I have no idea what your code does, but if you think it makes sense to call it in button events, then sure that will work.